# Can a contract be written that unlocks parts?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

Is it possible to write a contract that unlocks parts rather than, or in addition to, money or science?
I want to make it so that, for example, to unlock a better engine you would have to prove that the previous one was tested by taking it to an altitude above the ground, to simulate learning and using the part.

Comment: Is this a modding question?

Comment: Modding is on topic. The only thing that currently isn't that is related to modding is specifically modded Minecraft crash dump style tech support questions.

Comment: @Ash: Just asking for clarification, does this include both the usage of mods and the development of mods? Because OP is focusing on the latter and I thought only the former was considered on topic.

Comment: @user16973 , people at [this forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/KSPModDevelopment/) may be able to help you. BTW, great idea!!!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old. I started playing on version 1.6. But it's not answered today:

Contracts which order you to test some part, enable the part as "experimental".

You kind of unlock it. But only until you solve this mission.